# Module product and coproduct

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Completely lost when reading this:

"Defintion: If the index set $T$ is finite, the coproduct and product are the same module. If $T$ is infinite, the coproduct or sum
$$\coprod_{t\in T}M_t=\bigoplus_{t\in T}M_t=\oplus M_t$$
is the submodule of $\prod M_t$ consisting of all sequences $\{m_t\}$ with only a finite number of non-zero terms ..."

I think I understand what the product of module is. It's just like $n$-tuple $\{m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_n\}$ when $T={1,2,\cdots,n}$, but generalized to general index set $T$, right?

But what are coproducts? Submodule with finite number of non-zero terms only? Why need to restrict it to finite number? Why it is also called a sum?

Comment: Your guess is correct.  You need to restrict to finite numbers of nonzero terms so that it will be the coproduct: check the universal property.

Comment: I don't know category theory. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Oh, the product and coproduct are both defined in any category.  They each have a universal property: read wikipedia for specifics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct

Comment: In a specific category (like the category of R-modules) one must show that a coproduct actually exists, which is done by explicit construction.  To show that the construction is a coproduct one must check the universal property, which always determines the object up to isomorphism.

Comment: To understand the wiki you only need to learn the definition of category, which shouldn't be too hard if you are able to understand basic abstract algebra.  Worth doing in my opinion.